# CiviReports filtering on email adress

Tags: civireport, email

I want to display a report of all my contacts with a certain email adress ending, like "@gmail.com".

I find many reports that display email adress as the result, but I fail to find any report that can filter on email adress.

> Is there a CiviReport that can filter on email adress?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a core report that allows filtering by email.  Have you checked to see if there is one in an extension?

An alternative would be to create a smart group where the criteria is, for example, "%@gmail.com".  Most reports will let you filter by group.

Comment: Yes, I have checked most of the report extensions. Good idea with smart group! I solved it temporarily with a Drupal Views, but was looking for a CiviCRM report.